Add configuration to shared gradle plugin
I have migrated from groovy to kotlin in gradle and are restructuring the project accordingly. We had multiple groovy files not to let the main build.gradle get too big and unwieldy.
The apply(from = ... ) does not work with those files in kts, leaving the included files in groovy works but is ugly. This is also not recommended to use. From the docs I can see that a shared plugin is what I want to share configuration over multiple projects. However I cannot find any information on how to make it possible to configure a plugin.
As an example I want a plugin to encapsulate our common sonarqube configuration and apply the respective plugin:
plugins {
    id("org.sonarqube")
}

sonarqube {
    properties {
        property("sonar.projectKey", "individual_project")
        property("sonar.projectName", "Title that is different for each project")
        property("sonar.host.url", "https://sonar.somewhere.com")
        property("sonar.dependencyCheck.jsonReportPath", "./build/reports/dependency-check-report.json")
        property("sonar.dependencyCheck.htmlReportPath", "./build/reports/dependency-check-report.html")
    }
}

There is two fields, the title and project key that need to be set per project and are not static. I have not found any documentation on how to have dynamic values it seems all the examples in the gradle file are more or less adding either tasks or static stuff. How would you have dynamic values in a plugin or what would be the way to share configurable build code across projects?
Would using gradle.properties be an canonical way? Certain plugins I write just expect certain properties to be set?
Cheers

You can provide a custom extension to allow projects to configure the value. There are other ways such as using properties defined in gradle.properties, but that providing a dedicated DSL is more idiomatic.
This docs link is for tasks, but the concept is the same.
public abstract class MyExtension {

    public abstract Property<String> getProjectKey();

}

Then create the extension in your custom plugin:
public abstract class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    @Override
    public void apply(Project project) {
        project.getPluginManager().apply("org.sonarqube");
        project.getExtensions().create("myExtension", MyExtension.class);
    }
}

Which can then be used in the project as:
myExtension {
    projectKey = "com.example"
}

Which then be mapped to the sonar properties within the plugin:
public abstract class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    @Override
    public void apply(Project project) {
        project.getPluginManager().apply("org.sonarqube");
        ExtensionContainer extensions = project.getExtensions();
        MyExtension myExtension = extensions.create("myExtension", MyExtension.class);
        SonarExtension sonar = extensions.getByType(SonarExtension.class);
        sonar.properties(properties -> {
            properties.property("sonar.projectKey", myExtension.getProjectKey());
        });
    }
}

This is a pure Java example, but the concept is the same.
